# Blazor Testing which involves protected session storage

Tags: .net, unit-testing, blazor, blazor-server-side, xunit

System.InvalidOperationException
HResult=0x80131509
Message=Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.IDataProtectionProvider' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage.ProtectedSessionStorage'.
Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
StackTrace:
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
at Bunit.TestServiceProvider.GetServiceInternal(Type serviceType)
at Bunit.TestServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.g__Initialize|1(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IComponent component)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.PerformPropertyInjection(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IComponent instance)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.InstantiateComponent(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Type componentType)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InstantiateChildComponentOnFrame(RenderTreeFrame& frame, Int32 parentComponentId)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewComponentFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewSubtree(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 newFrameIndex)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.ComputeDiff(Renderer renderer, RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, Int32 componentId, ArrayRange`1 oldTree, ArrayRange`1 newTree)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment, Exception& renderFragmentException)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at Bunit.Rendering.TestRenderer.AssertNoUnhandledExceptions()
at Bunit.Rendering.TestRenderer.Render[TResult](RenderFragment renderFragment, Func`2 activator)
at Bunit.Rendering.TestRenderer.RenderFragment(RenderFragment renderFragment)
at Bunit.Extensions.TestContextBaseRenderExtensions.RenderInsideRenderTree(TestContextBase testContext, RenderFragment renderFragment)
at Bunit.Extensions.TestContextBaseRenderExtensions.RenderInsideRenderTree[TComponent](TestContextBase testContext, RenderFragment renderFragment)
at Bunit.TestContext.Render[TComponent](RenderFragment renderFragment)
at Bunit.TestContext.RenderComponent[TComponent](ComponentParameter[] parameters)
at ConfigWebappUnitTesting.AssetTableTest..ctor() in D:\Gleason Projects\ConfigurationWebAppBlazor\ConfigWebappUnitTesting\AssetTableTest.cs:line 19
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions)

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
[External Code]
ConfigWebappUnitTesting.AssetTableTest.AssetTableTest() in AssetTableTest.cs

AssetTable.cs with constructor

```
public AssetTableTest()
        {
            // Act
            var session = Context.Services.GetService<FakeSignOutSessionStateManager>();
            var page = Context.Services.GetService<FakeNavigationManager>();
            page.NavigateTo(page.BaseUri.Remove(page.BaseUri.Length - 1, 1) + Configuration["Session"]);
            cut = Context.RenderComponent<Assets>(); //**Got My error at this point**
            //cut = Context.RenderComponent<Assets>(x =>
            //x.Add(p => p.Session, Configuration["Session"])
            //);

            //WaitForAssertion
            cut.WaitForAssertion(() => { }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            cut.WaitForState(() => (cut.Markup.Contains("tbody")), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            cut.WaitForState(() => (!cut.Find("tbody").TextContent.Contains("Loading")), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50));
            tableBody = cut.Find("tbody");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

That exception is saying that you are missing a valid implementation for the `IDataProtectionProvider` service interface. In ASP.NET apps, this is typically done in `Program.cs` or `Startup.cs` (depending on the project and version of .NET). The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection` package [provides an extension method for `ServiceCollection` to accomplish this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/overview?view=aspnetcore-6.0#consuming-these-interfaces).

For you, it might look something like:

```csharp
// Assuming Context.Services is a ServiceCollection:
Context.Services.AddDataProtection();
```